# Change all VARCHAR columns to NVARCHAR

Tags: sql-server

I have about 200 columns in my database with `VARCHAR` type which is unable to store the rupee symbol. Now I have to change the datatype of all the columns from `VARCHAR` to `NVARCHAR`.

Can anyone please tell me the short way to accomplish this? And why does the `VARCHAR` support the pound sign and not the rupee sign? I'm asking because I have to change the pound symbol to rupee symbol.

Comment: try with nvarchar, it can store unicode characters also

Comment: why can't  you get table column name using INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS

Answer (score 13):

You can view all the columns, their data types and the table they belong using the ff query:

```
SELECT 
    t.name AS table_name,
    c.name AS column_name,
    tp.name AS data_type,
    c.max_length,
    c.is_nullable
FROM sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.columns c 
    ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
INNER JOIN sys.types tp
    ON tp.user_type_id = c.user_type_id
WHERE tp.name = 'varchar'
```

From the query above, you want to generate a dynamic sql that will change all your `VARCHAR` columns to `NVARCHAR`.

```
DECLARE @sql AS VARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SELECT @sql = @sql 
    + 'ALTER TABLE ' + table_name 
    + ' ALTER COLUMN ' + column_name + ' NVARCHAR(' 
        + CASE WHEN max_length <> - 1 THEN CAST(max_length AS VARCHAR(10))  ELSE 'MAX' END + ')'
        + CASE WHEN is_nullable = 1 THEN ' NULL' ELSE '' END
        + ';' + CHAR(10)
FROM (
    SELECT 
        t.name AS table_name,
        c.name AS column_name,
        tp.name AS data_type,
        c.max_length,
        c.is_nullable
    FROM sys.tables AS t
    INNER JOIN sys.columns c 
        ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
    INNER JOIN sys.types tp
        ON tp.user_type_id = c.user_type_id
    WHERE tp.name = 'varchar'
)t

PRINT @sql
EXEC(@sql)
```

Comment: Handy script, thanks. One tweak, remember data lengths are (chars*2)+2 for nvarchar (according to: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx), so to prevent truncation of existing data, you may want to change your script to use this: `CAST((max_length * 2) + 2 AS VARCHAR(10))`

Comment: The max_length value is the number of characters the field can hold. The article referenced in the previous comment is referring to the actual storage costs. If you want a varchar or a nvarchar to hold, say, 255 characters, the length would be defined in the same way: varchar(255) and nvarchar(255) respectively, and not nvarchar(512), so the stated answer is correct in my opinion

Comment: This adds "NULL" when the columns is nullable. This is unnecessary since a column is nullable by default. We should instead add "NOT NULL" when the column is not nullable. See here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_notnull.asp

Answer (score 5):

I met this issue today and Felix's answer worked quite well with one exception- if the column has default value defined. I researched a little bit and came up with the following script that drops and restores the default value.

Edited is_nullable line based on Fredrik's comment.

```
DECLARE @sql AS VARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SELECT @sql = @sql
    + CASE WHEN default_id>0 THEN 'ALTER TABLE '+table_name+' DROP CONSTRAINT '+OBJECT_NAME(default_id) +';'+CHAR(10) ELSE '' END
    + 'ALTER TABLE ' + table_name 
    + ' ALTER COLUMN ' + column_name + ' NVARCHAR(' 
        + CASE WHEN (max_length <> - 1 AND max_length<4001) THEN CAST(max_length AS VARCHAR(10))  ELSE 'MAX' END + ')'
        + CASE WHEN is_nullable = 1 THEN '' ELSE ' NOT NULL' END
        + ';' + CHAR(10)
    + CASE WHEN default_id>0 THEN 'ALTER TABLE '+table_name+' ADD DEFAULT '+default_value+' FOR '+column_name +';'+CHAR(10) ELSE '' END
FROM (
    SELECT 
        t.name AS table_name,
        c.name AS column_name,
        tp.name AS data_type,
        c.max_length,
        c.default_object_id AS default_id,
        OBJECT_DEFINITION(c.default_object_id) AS default_value,
        c.is_nullable
    FROM sys.tables AS t
    INNER JOIN sys.columns c 
        ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
    INNER JOIN sys.types tp
        ON tp.user_type_id = c.user_type_id
    WHERE tp.name = 'varchar'
)t

PRINT @sql
EXEC(@sql)
```

Comment: Ads the same comment here as in Felix's answer: This adds "NULL" when the columns is nullable. This is unnecessary since a column is nullable by default. We should instead add "NOT NULL" when the column is not nullable. See here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_notnull.asp

Answer (score 1):

Normally in sqlserver `VARCHAR` datatype allows only the **ANSI** Characters, But `NVARCHAR` allows **UNICODE** Character sets also, Pound symbol(156-ascii number), $ symbols are comes under ANSI character set.

So `VARCHAR` allows those.

But when u comes to the Rupee Symbol its recently invented so it comes under **UNICODE** character set, to achieve the rupee symbol we need to use rupees font or glyphs...
  Hope you understood y Pound comes under `VARCHAR` and Rupee Comes under `NVARCHAR`...

Comment: you have to edit your answer ASCII is 7 bit . and pound sign does not have an ascii. ASCII only defines codes 0-127 all other are extensions.just go through this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to Felix Pamittan's answer if you need to include schema.

```
DECLARE @sql AS VARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SELECT @sql = @sql 
    + 'ALTER TABLE ' + table_schema_name + '.' + table_name 
    + ' ALTER COLUMN ' + column_name + ' NVARCHAR(' 
        + CASE WHEN max_length <> - 1 THEN CAST(max_length AS VARCHAR(10))  ELSE 'MAX' END + ')'
        + CASE WHEN is_nullable = 1 THEN ' NULL' ELSE '' END
        + ';' + CHAR(10)
FROM (
    SELECT 
        sc.name AS table_schema_name,
        t.name AS table_name,
        c.name AS column_name,
        tp.name AS data_type,
        c.max_length,
        c.is_nullable
    FROM sys.tables AS t
    INNER JOIN sys.columns c 
        ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
    INNER JOIN sys.types tp
        ON tp.user_type_id = c.user_type_id
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas sc
        ON sc.schema_id = t.schema_id
    WHERE tp.name = 'varchar'
)t

PRINT @sql
EXEC(@sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will loop through all tables and their columns, and will generate query for updating those which have datatype as `varchar`

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(256), @ColumnName nvarchar(128), @Length nvarchar(128)
SET  @TableName = ''

WHILE @TableName IS NOT NULL

BEGIN
    SET @ColumnName = ''
    SET @TableName = 
    (
        SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME))
        FROM     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        WHERE         TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
            AND    QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) > @TableName
            AND    OBJECTPROPERTY(
                    OBJECT_ID(
                        QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)
                         ), 'IsMSShipped'
                           ) = 0
    )

    WHILE (@TableName IS NOT NULL) AND (@ColumnName IS NOT NULL)

    BEGIN
            SELECT @ColumnName=MIN(QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME)),@Length=MIN(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH)
            FROM     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            WHERE         TABLE_SCHEMA    = PARSENAME(@TableName, 2)
                AND    TABLE_NAME    = PARSENAME(@TableName, 1)
                --AND    DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'varchar', 'nchar', 'nvarchar', 'int', 'decimal')
                AND    DATA_TYPE IN ('varchar')
                AND    QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) > @ColumnName


        IF @ColumnName IS NOT NULL and @Length > 0

        BEGIN

            print (' ALTER TABLE ' +@TableName+ ' ALTER COLUMN ' + @ColumnName + ' NVARCHAR('+@Length+')')

            --exec (@dSql)

        END
    END    
END
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE' +QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA)+'.'+QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)+ 'ALTER COLUMN ' + COLUMN_NAME + ' NVARCHAR(100)'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'TAbleName'
```